# Count the transactions from each with the status CANCELLED per day

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| id | status    | Transaction date    | Vendor    | Customer ID          |
|  1 | Completed | 2019-11-15 11:46:11 | Vendor A  | 12345                |
|  2 | Completed | 2019-11-14 23:03:24 | Vendor B  | 67891                |
|  3 | Completed | 2019-11-15 12:04:13 | Vendor C  | 456                  |
|  4 | Cancelled | 2019-11-14 11:46:11 | Vendor A  | 22225                |
|  5 | Cancelled | 2019-11-20 23:03:24 | Vendor B  | 789999               |
|  6 | Cancelled | 2019-11-20 12:04:13 | Vendor C  | 789999               |
```

can you help me to count the transactions from each vendor with the status CANCELLED per day guys?
i'm trying but failed

```
EXPECTATION

Transaction date    | Vendor    | TOTAL TRANSACTION
2019-11-14          | Vendor A  | 1
2019-11-20          | Vendor B  | 1
2019-11-20          | Vendor C  | 1
```

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). See the help center for more on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics.

Comment: Problem statements should include desired and actual results.

Comment: oke @outis, i put my expectation, can you help me please?

Comment: the expectation does not count the cancelled transaction...

Comment: This doesn't seem well worded are you matching cancellations to completions based on vendor and datetime to arrive at a count? and you don't care which customer id is in the output?

Comment: revised bro sorry @dcolazin

Comment: Why did you remove the attempted query? Expected/desired results don't take the place of sample code. You still haven't created a [mcve]; read over the link articles in my first comment and apply their advice. Also, I strongly suspect this question is a duplicate. Did you check whether a similar question existed?

Comment: Other questions possibly covering this one: "[Complex SQL query for getting the status of orders](//stackoverflow.com/q/50994306/90527)", "[How do you get a total count for each events in between each full hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68332614/90527)", "[Querying for status updates per day from an audit log of version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12393086/90527)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you want the following, which is not what you requested. This is a simple `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT date(transaction_date), vendor, count(*)
FROM table
WHERE status = 'Cancelled'
GROUP BY transaction_date, vendor
```

Comment: Thanks guys,
i'm using this

`SELECT
DATE(transaction_date) as "Transaction date",
   Vendor,
   COUNT(*) as "TOTAL TRANSACTION" 
FROM transactions_server.transactions
WHERE
   status = "CANCELLED" 
GROUP BY
   DATE(transaction_date);`

Comment: @xylazer if you group by date, this will not work if there are more than one vendor for some days